# How to fetch posts of LinkedIn users using LinkedIn API without r_member_social

Tags: curl, linkedin-api

I read in many articels that for fetching the user's posts, "r_member_social" this permission is needed. I was unable to find that permission and recently I read in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2023-06) article that currently the request to this permission is not being accepted.

So other than this, is there any alternative to fetch user's post?

[image]

I tried the below API in postman, with correct authorization bearer and id, but the postman shows

> "Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares"

```
curl  -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer token<>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:{id}'
```